# How can I process an input to an output file line-by-line in Java?

Tags: java, file, input, file-io, output

I am trying to read from a .txt file (line-by-line) to convert an expression from prefix to postfix. I am using the following code to read and output. How can I pass the input into **PrefixtoPosfix()** method, process it then outputs the outcome into a text file.

example:
if the prefix input file is *(+ * A B / C D)*, it will convert it using the method I have for it in the program **PrefixtoPosfix()** and output *A B * C D / +* in the output file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader inputStream = null;
    FileWriter outputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new FileReader("input.txt"); // input file
        outputStream = new FileWriter("output.txt"); // output file

        int c;
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) { // read and process one character
            if (c == 'a') // replace all occurrences of 'a' with '@'
                outputStream.write('@');
            else outputStream.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
        if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `FileReader` in a `BufferedReader` instead.  It has a `readLine()` method.

Comment: What about writing to file?

Comment: If most `Reader` objects have an associated `Writer`, what objects do you think you will need?